# Calling ajax function from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

The following code called when clicked a button and call the insert
_all function that is an ajax function. In success I put an alert but not working the json call liquidations_a_insert_all.jsp is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#click1').click(function(event) {
     var auditorid = $('input:hidden[id=Wauditorid]').val();
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'groupauditors.jsp',
         data: {
             Woauditorid: auditorid
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
             $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    var currRow = $("#tr0").clone().appendTo($('#items')).attr('id','tr' + (index + 1));
                    currRow.find('td:eq(0)').html(index + 1);
                    currRow.find('.subgroupid').html(element.subgroupid);
                    currRow.find('.auditorid').html(element.auditorid);

                    insert_all(element.auditorid, "", "");
             });
         }
        });
    });
});
```

that call the  insert_all(element.auditorid, "", "");

```
function insert_all(auditorid, onSuccess, onFail) {
 $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'liquidations_a_insert_all.jsp',
         data: {
             Wauditorid: auditorid
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
                    alert("insert_all");
//$( 'table tbody tr td:last-child').html(data.inserted);
                    }
     });
 }
```

Any idea?

Comment: maybe the data returned is not of type json did you check?

Comment: Are you sure that `insert_all` is actually being called?

Comment: Pekka you have right, I had jsp tag that corrupt the json type.

Comment: please accept my ans

Answer (score 1):

I hope Using  `async:false,` in Both ajax Function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#click1').click(function(event) {
     var auditorid = $('input:hidden[id=Wauditorid]').val();
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'groupauditors.jsp',
         data: {
             Woauditorid: auditorid
         },
         async:false,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
             $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    var currRow = $("#tr0").clone().appendTo($('#items')).attr('id','tr' + (index + 1));
                    currRow.find('td:eq(0)').html(index + 1);
                    currRow.find('.subgroupid').html(element.subgroupid);
                    currRow.find('.auditorid').html(element.auditorid);

                    insert_all(element.auditorid, "", "");
             });
         }
        });
    });
});


function insert_all(auditorid, onSuccess, onFail) {
 $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'liquidations_a_insert_all.jsp',
         data: {
             Wauditorid: auditorid
         },
         async:false,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
                    alert("insert_all");
//$( 'table tbody tr td:last-child').html(data.inserted);
                    }
     });
 }
```